# How is it possible to find all occurrences of a method if the Visual Studio „Find All References“ does not work?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

The special case I am dealing with is to find all usages of the method
[CTime::Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/ctime-class?view=msvc-160#format) in the entire solution. Please assume that the Visual Studio functionality „Find All References“ does not work for this case.

Comment: `does not work` is too strong of a blanket statement. While it may not meet all your needs and/or expectations, "*Find All References*" does largely work as advertised. Outstanding, reproducible bugs should be reported [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/62/index.html).

Comment: If you are allowed to change your C++ compiler, you could switch to [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and write your [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In order to find all usages of the method CTime::Format follow the steps:

**Step 1:** Replace the string CTime by the string CCTime in the entire solution.

**Step 2:** Implement the following:

```
#include "atltime.h"

class CCTime : public CTime
{
public:
    [[deprecated("--> uses the method CTime::Format")]]
    CString Format(LPCTSTR pszFormat) const
    {
        return CString(_T(" "));
    }
};
```

**Step 3:** Rebuild the entire solution in order to get compile errors at the correct spots.

Comment: *Step 2* will need more work for all legitimate `CTime` code to compile correctly using `CCTime` instead.

Comment: Ok, can you please point out what you mean in detail with "Step 2 will need more work"?

Comment: For example `CTime t0(0), t1{ _time64(NULL) };` will no longer compile with `CCTime` unless you add the appropriate constructors.

Comment: Dangerous advice from someone that doesn't acknowledge the complexity of overload resolution in C++. Heavy-handed, too. Like your previous question this is the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) all over again.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.